# Como obtener el producto por id al hacer click en boton con VUE?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, vue.js, vuex

Tengo la siguiente funcion y necesito transformarla para poder incluirla en mi pagina con Vue:

```
/**
     * Obtiene el producto por id y completa el formulario con la info en caso de exito
     * @param productId
     */
    this.getProductById = function(productId) {
        showMainContentLoading();
        $("#product-form").removeClass('preventLeavingForm');

        var jqxhr = $.post('/stock/ajaxFindProduct/', {id: productId}, null, 'json')
            .fail(function (data) {
                messageManager.showErrorMessage(i18nHelper.getText('No se ha podido encontrar el producto seleccionado'));
            })
            .always(function (data) {
                removeMainContentLoading();
            });

        return jqxhr;
    };
```

En Vue tengo un link de un producto seleccionado por el cliente, que al clickear lo debe redirigir a la pagina de `/stock/product/` + el producto seleccionado.

```
<b-link
        @click="openProductDetail()"
      >
        {{ row.item.name }}
      </b-link>
```

Como transformarla e incluirla correctamente en Vue?
No estoy utilizando Vue router en este caso.

Comment: Si usas vue-router en la documentación sale como poder enviarle parámetros por url, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298071/8051206) tiene el ejemplo.

Comment: gracias @SebastiánLagosYañez justamente no estoy usando vue router, por eso necesitaria alguna manera distinta.

Comment: que hace la función openProductDetail exactamente???

Comment: openProductDetail (id, event) { window.location.href = `/stock/products/${id}` } @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas por ahora es lo que tengo, pero al tener la funcion que pasé en la consulta, pienso que hay una manera de hacerlo correctamente la cual no estoy pudiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de no usar vue-router la opción que no recomendaría mucho pero que ciertamente serviría en este caso, seria usar directamente window.location

```
    openProductDetail(idProducto) {
      window.location.href = '/stock/product/' + idProducto; //Dominio relativo
    }
```

También depende desde que parte este redirigiendo

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné con:

```
openProductDetail (id, event) {
      window.location.href = `/stock/product/${id}`
    }
```